# How to iterate over a http response(json) in angular service method, to generate a customized json?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting http response like this:

```
[
    {"id": "1", "name": "2", "value": "3", "any": "4"}
]
```

I want to convert it to something like this:

```
[
{
    "heading": "id"
    "content": "1"
},
{
    "heading": "name"
    "content": 2
},
{
    "heading": "value"
    "content": 3
},
{
    "heading": "any"
    "content": 4
}
]
```

I am using angular4.0.0 and I want to perform this in service method.
How to achieve this result?

Comment: what have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: for and foreach loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

```js
var arrayData = [
    {"id": "1", "name": "2", "value": "3", "any": "4"}
]

let finalArray = arrayData.map(el => {
  let returnArray = [];
  for(let key in el){
     returnArray.push({heading : key , content : el[key]})
  }
  return returnArray;
})

console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: You return an array inside an array, it is not exactly the expected output. You must probably remove the `map` ;)

Comment: @sjahan , I have provided the solution is global , it will work for any number of result in `arrayData` , What you are saying was easy. :) , OP should understand code. :D

Answer (score 1):

```js
var response = [
    {"id": "1", "name": "2", "value": "3", "any": "4"}
];

var newJson = [];
response.forEach(function(val,index){
  Object.keys(val).forEach(function(data) {
      newJson.push({heading: data,content:val[data]})
  })
  console.log(newJson)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var responseData=[
    {"id": "1", "name": "2", "value": "3", "any": "4"}
];

var finalResult = [];
responseData.map(function(item){
var test = [];
var allKeys=Object.keys(item);
for(i=0;i<allKeys.length;i++)
{
finalResult.push({'heading':allKeys[i],'content':item[allKeys[i]]});
}
});

console.log(finalResult)
```